# Animation Function runs but returns "The expression ... cannot be used as part specification" while running

Tags: graphics

```
randomWalkC[n_] := Module[{column, row, ball, coordinates},
   x = n/2;
   y = n/2;
   coordinates = {{x, y}};
While[Between[x, {0, n}] && Between[y, {0, n}], 
r = RandomInteger[{1, 4}];
If[r == 1, x = x + 1];
If[r == 2, x = x - 1];
If[r == 3, y = y + 1];
If[r == 4, y = y - 1];
AppendTo[coordinates, {x, y}]
];
N[coordinates]
];

(*this function gives the motion of the walker
 c is a list of coordinates that the ball will be at
 column is the columns of the graph
 row is the rows of the graph*)

randomWalk[n_] := Module[{column, row, ball, c},
  c = randomWalkC[n];
  column = Graphics[Table[Line[{{a, 0}, {a, n}}], {a, 0, n}]];
  row = Graphics[Table[Line[{{0, a}, {n, a}}], {a, 0, n}]];
  Animate[ball = Graphics[{Red, Disk[c[[i]], 0.3]}];
   Show[row, column, ball],
   {i, 1, Length[c],
    AnimationRunning -> False,
    AnimationRepetitions -> 1}]
  ]

randomWalk[5]
```

When I run the program the program does run, however it is red and shows and error message when hovering mouse on the animation. I don't know where the number is coming from. I've run the function without the animation (so only the end result) and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: change your iterator to  `{i, 1, Length[c], 1, AnimationRunning -> False, 
 AnimationRepetitions -> 1}`?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, It worked.